# How to cache php / static page in Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have installed one WordPress site on my ec2 instance and already store and access all the images on Amazon S3 Bucket with the offload S3 plugin. I want to make page cache of all the PHP page. Is it any mechanism or plugin available for this?

I have referred [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/startups/how-to-accelerate-your-wordpress-site-with-amazon-cloudfront/) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since wordpress uses PHP to generate pages, you can't use S3 to cache them.

However, you have a couple of options if the goal is to speed up your site.

Option 1 is to use CloudFront, a CDN, in front of your site.  This would require you to cache the generated pages for a certain timeframe, which means if you do update content, it will not show up for your end users immediately unless you invalidate the cloudfront cache.

Option 2 is to export the entire site to static pages, and serve those out of S3.  The benefit of this is that it will be much cheaper to host your site; the downside is that you will have to refresh the S3 content every time you make a change.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I got it. For option 1, I have already integrated CloudFront. But for Option 2 my pages are coming from the DB (Dynamic) so I guess it is not possible to host my site on S3.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to upload s3 bucket images into the cloud front?

Comment: You do not upload anything to Cloudfront.  You set your S3 bucket as an origin, and Cloudfront will take care of retrieving and caching files.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the reply. How can I rewrite URL for the s3 bucket object? 
for eg. `http://awsspecin.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/30105407/xxx.png    ->  
 http://d29ghn7c94rlhzqw.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/30105407/xxx.png`